# Angular FormArray does not load control when used with *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-forms, formarray

I have built a dynamic table component that will create a table based on your rows and columns input. It works great when the table is already present or when hidden using the "[hidden]" attribute but not so well when used with *ngIf.

When using ngIf it throws a console error every time I try to add a new row and creates the controls incorrectly but when I click on the control it corrects itself and adds the correct controls to the columns.

Does anyone know if this is angular related issue or just something that I am not handling correctly?

- this is when I click on a button to add a new row: I get a text box that covers the entire row.
  [image] [image]
- this is after I click on the text box
  [image]

  ```js
  export class DynamicTableComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() columns: Column[] = [];
    rows: string[];

    tableForm: FormGroup;
    formArray: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);

    constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.tableForm = this.fb.group({});
      this.tableForm.addControl('rows', this.formArray);
    }

    getData(idx: number): FormArray {
      return this.formArray.at(idx) as FormArray;
    }

    getType(formControl: AbstractControl): string {
      return formControl.get('type')?.value as string;
    }

    addRow(): void {
      const row = this.fb.array([]);

      this.columns.forEach((col) => {
        const fieldValue = 'Placeholder text';
        row.push(
          this.fb.group({
            columnName: col.name,
            type: col.type,
            value: fieldValue,
          })
        );
      });

      this.formArray.push(row);
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <form id="dynamic-table" [formGroup]="tableForm">
    <table>
      <tbody formArrayName="rows">
        <ng-container *ngIf="formArray">
          <ng-container
            *ngFor="let row of formArray.controls; let i = index"
            [formGroupName]="i">
            <tr [id]="'row-' + i">
              <ng-container
                *ngFor="
                  let cell of getData(i).controls;
                  let j= index"
                [formGroupName]="j">
                <ng-container [ngSwitch]="getType(cell)">
                  <td *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [id]="'col-' + j">
                    <pre> A text field component.</pre>
                  </td>
                  <td *ngSwitchCase="'tickBox'" [id]="'col-' + j">
                    <pre>A checkbox component.</pre>
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
              </ng-container>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  ```

Comment: just a stab in the dark, but `[formGroupName]="i"` seems like a bad idea if the table is dynamic. you probably want something more like `[formGroupName]="row.id"`

Answer (score 0):

first you should call the addRow() function in your NgOnInit(), and fill the data in the formArray.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out  `this.tableForm.addControl('rows', this.formArray);` copied this.formArray by value and not ref, I assumed it would be passed by ref as it is a controller.

The issue was resolved after I started using get() function to access and update the form control in the main form.